# Exclude advertisements from social sharing thumbnail options

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, thumbnails, reddit

Awhile back I noticed that social linking sites such as Reddit, StumbleUpon and Facebook would often grab advertisements running on my site as the thumbnail image for shared pages. I didn't want that to happen, obviously, so I added a default image link to the header: `<link rel="image_src" href="http://gapersblock.com/gfx/default_thumb.jpg"/>`

Problem half-solved. Now the default image is the *only* image sharing sites see, whether there are other images on the page or not. I'd like readers to be able to choose other images from the page if they want. Is there some code I can wrap our ad invocation code in to "hide" it from sharing sites, or at least make it less? Is there a way to tell these sites' thumbnail generators "Pick whatever you want, except this ad right here, or use this default image if that's all you can find"?

Relevant background: I'm using Movable Type, so Wordpress advice is useless to me. I'm comfortable with HTML and CSS, but a novice on javascript or php.

Answer (score 0):

You would just need to add multiple image_src tags for all the images you want users to be able to pick from.